# Installation of pygtk not working

Tags: python, installation, 64-bit, pygtk

I am running on Windows (64bit version) and have python 2.7 (also 64 bit) installed. I downloaded the all-in-one installer for pygtk for python 2.7, but when I run it, it shows "python 2.7 could not be located on your system". Why is it so when I already have python 2.7 installed?

Answer (score 10):

Currently, the all-in-one installer binaries [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.22/) are compiled against 32 bits python only. There is no 64 bits binary in there. Install python 2.7 32 bits on your windows and it should work.

Alternatively, you could grab a C compiler, and then try to compile [the installer sources](https://github.com/dieterv/pygtk-installer%20an). That's a lot harder though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install a 64bit Python interpreter? The most probable reason
for that message is that the all-in-one installer **can't locate** a 32bit
Python interpreter (which works fine on 64bit Windows).

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.gtk+.python/15263